# Classification Function to check more then one Column

Tags: python, pandas

I use two  Columns to do identify specifics products on my data.

###### Example Dataframe with foo_data

|  | ncm_code | product_description |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 27101932 | EXXON S-10 |
| 1 | 27101932 | LUBRAX S-10 |
| 2 | 27101932 | OIL |
| 3 | 36101932 | OIL |
| 4 | 84713012 | NOTEBOOK IDEAPAD (1162) |
| 5 | 84713012 | WI-FI ACCESS POINT 6 |
| 6 | 84713012 | ETHERNET ROUTER MODEL 000123 |

###### My Analysis

- Classification could be done checking just `product_description`.
- Classification could be done checking just `ncm_code`
- Classification could be done checking `ncm_code` and `product_description`.

###### My aproach, so far

> I am open to more pythonic suggestions.

```py
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(foo_data)
foo_data = { 'ncm_code': ['27101932', '27101932', '27101932', '36101932', '84713012', '84713012', '84713012'],
             'product_description': ['EXXON S-10','LUBRAX S-10', 'OIL',
                                     'OIL', 'NOTEBOOK IDEAPAD (1162)', 'WI-FI ACCESS POINT 6', 
                                     'ETHERNET ROUTER MODEL 000123']}
def foo_func(x):
    fuel_words = ['LUBRAX', 'EXXON', 'GASOLINE', 'PETROL', 'OIL']
    info_words = ['ACCESS POINT','DRIVE CD/DVD', 'DISPLAYPORT', 'NOTEBOOK', 'CPU', 'SWITCH', 
                 'MICROCOMP','TABLET', 'DDR', 'PATCH PANEL', 'HDMI', 'VGA', 'STORAGE', 
                 'ETHERNET', 'FIREWAL' , 'CORE I3', 'CORE I5', 'CORE I7', 'COREI3','CORE I5', 'CORE I7']
    if any(item in x for item in info_words):
        return 'INFO'
    elif any(item in x for item in fuel_words):
        return 'FUEL'

df['desired_class'] = df['product_description'].apply(foo_func)
df
```

###### my question

This code is just check one column `product_description`.
**How could I adapt the analysis so that the function would analyze two columns???**

###### Expected Output

|  | ncm_code | product_description | desired_output |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 27101932 | EXXON S-10 | FUEL |
| 1 | 27101932 | LUBRAX S-10 | FUEL |
| 2 | 27101932 | OIL | FUEL |
| 3 | 36101932 | OIL | MINERAL OIL |
| 4 | 84713012 | NOTEBOOK IDEAPAD (1162) | INFO |
| 5 | 84713012 | WI-FI ACCESS POINT 6 | INFO |
| 6 | 84713012 | ETHERNET ROUTER MODEL 000123 | INFO |

###### The problem

Line `index = 3` should be 'MINERAL OIL' cause of the `ncm_code`

My code is not cheching `ncm_code`

I want to improve my code to check `ncm_code` and  `desired_output`

Thanks.

##### Solution:

> Thanks to @Laurent

```py
def foo_func(x, y):
    fuel_words = ['LUBRAX', 'EXXON', 'GASOLINE', 'PETROL', 'OIL']
    info_words = ['ACCESS POINT','DRIVE CD/DVD', 'DISPLAYPORT', 'NOTEBOOK', 'CPU', 'SWITCH', 
                 'MICROCOMP','TABLET', 'DDR', 'PATCH PANEL', 'HDMI', 'VGA', 'STORAGE', 
                 'ETHERNET', 'FIREWAL' , 'CORE I3', 'CORE I5', 'CORE I7', 'COREI3','CORE I5', 'CORE I7']
    if any(item in x for item in info_words):
        return "INFO"
    if any(item in x for item in fuel_words) and y == "36101932":
        return "MINERAL OIL"
    return "FUEL"


df["desired_output"] = df.apply(
    lambda df_: foo_func(df_["product_description"], df_["ncm_code"]), axis=1
)
```

Comment: The easiest solution to add one more col for unique ID which is ncm_code +product_description

Comment: @NoobVB seems to be an alternative.   But with this I will have to if the 8 first digits are in a list...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one way to modify your function:

```py
def foo_func(x, y):
    fuel_words = ['LUBRAX', 'EXXON', 'GASOLINE', 'PETROL', 'OIL']
    info_words = ['ACCESS POINT','DRIVE CD/DVD', 'DISPLAYPORT', 'NOTEBOOK', 'CPU', 'SWITCH', 
                 'MICROCOMP','TABLET', 'DDR', 'PATCH PANEL', 'HDMI', 'VGA', 'STORAGE', 
                 'ETHERNET', 'FIREWAL' , 'CORE I3', 'CORE I5', 'CORE I7', 'COREI3','CORE I5', 'CORE I7']
    if any(item in x for item in info_words):
        return "INFO"
    if any(item in x for item in fuel_words) and y == "36101932":
        return "MINERAL OIL"
    return "FUEL"
```

And then:

```py
df["desired_output"] = df.apply(
    lambda df_: foo_func(df_["product_description"], df_["ncm_code"]), axis=1
)
```

```py
print(df)
# Output
   ncm_code           product_description desired_output
0  27101932                    EXXON S-10           FUEL
1  27101932                   LUBRAX S-10           FUEL
2  27101932                           OIL           FUEL
3  36101932                           OIL    MINERAL OIL
4  84713012       NOTEBOOK IDEAPAD (1162)           INFO
5  84713012          WI-FI ACCESS POINT 6           INFO
6  84713012  ETHERNET ROUTER MODEL 000123           INFO
```

Comment: I think this approach, with little tweaks, will do the job.  Thank you very much!